# How to use 'python-config' command in Windows?

Tags: python, makefile

I'm trying to build a deep learning code in Windows.

However, due to the different target OS, it has problems to use "make".

There is a makefile below:

```
CXXFLAGS = -I include  -std=c++11 -O3 $(shell python3-config --cflags)
CXXFLAGS := $(filter-out -fno-plt -mtune=haswell, $(CXXFLAGS))
LDFLAGS = $(shell python3-config --ldflags)

DEPS = lanms.h $(shell find include -xtype f)
CXX_SOURCES = adaptor.cpp include/clipper/clipper.cpp

LIB_SO = adaptor.so

$(LIB_SO): $(CXX_SOURCES) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(CXX_SOURCES) --shared -fPIC

clean:
    rm -rf $(LIB_SO)
```

And in this file, there are commands, "shell python3-config --cflags" and "shell python3-config --ldflags", which do not exist in Windows.

How can I replace them to run in Windows?

Comment: This is just the tip of the iceberg.  If this code was not already ported to run in Windows, then it will most likely take a LOT of work to make it do so.  Even the `find` command in Windows is totally different than `find` in a UNIX system, and the Windows compiler (MSVC) doesn't use the `--shared` or `-fPIC` flags.  Windows doesn't use `.so` for shared libraries.  If you're not well-familiar with the effort involved in porting code from a UNIX system to Windows, it will be a serious undertaking to learn it all.